# Why heap allocation uses a lot of memory than stack allocation?

Tags: c++, memory

I wonder why stack allocation use less memory than heap allocation? The gap between this allocation is really huge. When I use stack. It consumes around ~77MB, but when I use heap allocation. It consumes ~880MB. There is no memory leak (I guess), because after I delete this object the memory return completely (back to less than 1KB like before this function called).

here is stack allocation ~77 MB

```
void LoadZone() //this fuction is called over 700 times
{
    FILE* file; //this file contains data in binary (~54KB)
    std::string filepath = "./map/" + std::to_string(MapId); //private member int MapId

    errno_t e = fopen_s(&file, filepath.c_str(), "rb");

    fread(&XLength, 1, sizeof(short), file); //private member short XLength
    fread(&YLength, 1, sizeof(short), file); //private member short YLength

    MapGrid.reserve(YLength); //private member : MapGrid is std::vector<std::vector<GridPos>>
    for (short y = 0; y < YLength; ++y)
    {
        //GridPos contains short X,Y  char Value
        std::vector<GridPos> data;
        data.reserve(XLength);
        for (short x = 0; x < XLength; ++x)
        {
            data.emplace_back(x, y, (char)std::getc(file));
        }
        MapGrid.push_back(data);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

here is heap allocation ~880 MB

```
void LoadZone() //this fuction is called over 700 times
{
    FILE* file; //this file contains data in binary (~54KB)
    std::string filepath = "./map/" + std::to_string(MapId); //private member int MapId

    errno_t e = fopen_s(&file, filepath.c_str(), "rb");

    fread(&XLength, 1, sizeof(short), file); //private member short XLength
    fread(&YLength, 1, sizeof(short), file); //private member short XLength

    MapGrid.resize(YLength); //private member : MapGrid is std::vector<std::vector<GridPos*>>
    for (short y = 0; y < YLength; ++y)
    {
        //GridPos contains short X,Y  char Value
        std::vector<GridPos*> data;
        data.resize(XLength);
        for (short x = 0; x < XLength; ++x)
        {
            data.push_back(new GridPos(x, y, (char)std::getc(file)));
        }
        MapGrid.push_back(data);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to include a [mre].

Comment: You don't have stack allocations in the first example. The both example use the memory heap. The first example allocates continuing memory for GridPos objects in the heap, the second example meanwhile allocates continuing memory for pointers and many unique small objects in the heap. @DanielLangr's answer about the memory consumption is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heap allocations are all aligned to some minimal value (see `_STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`). For instance, with glibc on x86_64, it is typically 16. This basically means that the heap always allocates at least 16 bytes, even if you ask for a single one. There are generally some bytes wasted. Consequently, when you allocate multiple objects on the stack, they can be placed next to each other in the memory, but this does not hold for heap-allocated data.

Second, a heap needs some housekeeping data. Again, with glibc and x86_64, this is usually something like 16 bytes.

As a summary, if you allocate say a single `int` object, which requires 4 bytes, the heap consumes 32 bytes of memory for this allocation. You can simply benchmark this (allocate say 100M of integers and measure max RSS).